# How do you set vagrant environment variable VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vmware-fusion

I have not found any information on how to explicitly set vagrant environment variables.

I'm trying to do what's described in these [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/default.html) to set `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` to `vmware_fusion` so I don't always have to use `vagrant up --provider=vmware_fusion`.

I have put this line in my Vagrantfile.

`VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER = "vmware_fusion"`

It doesn't work, and I assume that must mean I have no idea what I'm doing, and must be doing it wrong. When I run `vagrant up` it still uses the default virtualbox provider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to issue

```sh
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER="vmware_fusion"
```

in your shell. To make the change permanent add this line to your .bashrc/.bash_profile.

Comment: Oh, that kind of environment variable! :) Thank you much!

Comment: I don't know about all platforms, but on Mac OSX, you can't have the extra spaces around the equals sign, after deleting those, it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the default provider for a specific project only, you *can* set it also in Vagrantfile:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = "vmware_fusion"

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...
end
```